# Allow insecure localhost flag no longer available on new Chrome Version

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, localhost

In older versions of Chrome, there was a flag you could enable "chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost" to ignore invalid SSL certificates for localhost.

In the newer Chrome versions (Version 119.0.6045.124) this flag is no longer available. However there is a new flag:
[image]

This flag still causes the following issue even after proceeding:

[image]

Is there a work-around for this issue?

I have cleared the local SSL state and reset Chrome.

Comment: There is a long complaint thread in the google support community as well: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/241869686/allow-insecure-localhost-has-been-removed-as-of-chrome-119?hl=en

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try enabling this "#temporary-unexpire-flags-m118" [Google chrome article](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/241869686/allow-insecure-localhost-has-been-removed-as-of-chrome-119?hl=en) flag first.

And then you can search for "chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost".
[image]

Comment: The problem about the temporarily unexpire M118 flag is, that it is entirely unclear how long this will work, as even its name says that it's temporary

Answer (score -6):

just download the old version and delete chromeupdate file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update and it will be good to go